# Texture Reading in Fragment Shader

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am passing a texture to a fragment shader I want to mix the texture color in that pixel value with Blue color Alpha 0.2 How can I do that ?

Fragment Shader

```
fragment float4 bezier_fragment(VertexOutBezier params[[stage_in]],
                                texture2d<float> texture [[texture(0)]]
```

VertexOutBezier

```
struct VertexOutBezier {
    float4 pos[[position]];
    float4 color;

};
```

Currently I am doing like this but i am getting a error in this shader function in sample. " No matching member function for call to 'sample' " in the line of float canvasColor Initialization

```
fragment float4 bezier_fragment(VertexOutBezier params[[stage_in]],
                                texture2d<float> texture [[texture(0)]]
                                )
{
    constexpr sampler defaultSampler;
    float4 canvasColor = texture.sample(defaultSampler, params.pos);
    float4 finalColor = mix(canvasColor, params.color, 0.2);
    return finalColor;
}
```

Comment: When you post a question like this, you should show the **complete** compiler output, verbatim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
float4 canvasColor = texture.sample(defaultSampler, params.pos);
```

with

```
float4 canvasColor = texture.sample(defaultSampler, params.pos.xy);
```

2D textures are sampled by 2 coordinates, you provided 4.